# Saving and logging mlflow custom model

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, mlflow

I am trying to use mlflow in Azure databricks for a custom ML model I have created. I am however new to mlflow so to get an idea of how to save and log the model I have created a small example from the mlflow documentation that I am trying to make work.

```
import pandas as pd
import mlflow

# Define the model class
class AddN(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def predict(self, context, model_input):
        return model_input.apply(lambda column: column + self.n)

model_input = pd.DataFrame([range(10)])
model_path = r"/FileStore/tmp/<folder path>"
add5_model = AddN(n=5)

with mlflow.start_run(run_name="test_forecast") as run:
  model_path = f"{model_path}-{run.info.run_uuid}"
  mlflow.log_param("algorithm", "AddN")
  mlflow.log_param("total_n_values", len(model_input))
  mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(path=model_path, python_model=add5_model)
```

This block of code will run and when I go to **Experiments** in Databricks I can see the parameters I have saved with the correct Run Name but when I press the Version I am taken to total white Azure Devops page - *why is this?*

Futher, when I go to the `model_path` folder I see no files. Currently I am setting the path to an empty folder in Azure Databricks DBFS - *but I am unsure if this is the correct way and the reason to that I don't see any files?*

I also want to log the model, as to why I have also added the following block of code:

```
reg_model_name = "ml_flow_AddN_test"

mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(artifact_path=model_path,
                        python_model = add5_model,
                        registered_model_name=reg_model_name)
```

However, when I further run this I get following error:
`RestException: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Invalid value '/FileStore/tmp/<folder-path>-111a11a111111a1a1111aa11111a1a11/requirements.txt' for parameter: 'path'. Path must be relative.` (I have substituted the text after the `<folder-path>` with a similar example to what I get - I assume it is some sort of mlflow id?) - *How do I solve this error?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mlflow.pyfunc.log_model` function's `artifact_path` parameter, is [defined as](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/pyfunc/__init__.py#L1369) :

```
:param artifact_path: The run-relative artifact path to which to log the Python model.
```

That means, it is just a name that should identify the model in the context of that run and hence cannot be an absolute path like what you passed in. Try something short like `add5_model`.

```py
reg_model_name = "ml_flow_AddN_test"

mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(artifact_path= "add5_model",
                        python_model = add5_model,
                        registered_model_name=reg_model_name)
```